# Good sources for Data-sets for word problems of Calculus

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am currently working on a project involving solving word problems of Calculus through Natural Language Processing, AI algorithm. I tried to find a data-set for word problems of Calculus but could not find it. So can anyone please suggest some good sources for word problems of Calculus suited for NLP.